# c++ use 1D Array with 2D Data

Tags: c++, arrays, fftw

I do not use any matrix library, but instead plain std::vector for my matrix data.

To fill it with 2D data I use this code:

```
data[iy + dataPointsY * ix] = value;
```

I would like to know is this is correct or if it must be the other way (ix first).
To my understanding fftw needs 'Row-major Format'. Since I use it the formula should be according to row-major format.

Comment: The key point is, they way you store the data should be exactly the way you retrieve.

Comment: sure, but I know that other libs rely on row.major format. Since I use it I should order the data according to it.

Comment: If you are trying to encode the 2d indexing in a linear format which some other library expects, then you have to follow exactly the format specified by that library. Like MPI functions would require all the data elements of a matrix should be adjacent in memory.

Comment: Also, if you traverse the matrix column wise, (that is top to bottom for one single column), then you should consider storing it in a column-major format, as in that case the elements would be adjacent, allowing large datasets being traversed in lesser page faults.

Comment: The question is not whether this format is "correct". The question is what format does the fftw library expect.

Comment: Let's look at how you access your data to find out: `data[y + Y * x]`. Your `y`s are sequential in memory and your `x`s are `Y` elements appart. I.e. for `data` to be row-major, `y` needs to index the column and `x` the row.

Comment: Recommend wrapping that indexing math one way or another. If you keep typing it over and over sooner or later there will be a sucktastic and hard-to-spot typo.

Comment: This was an example. In most of my own code this is an inline function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want row major format for `fftw`, what you want is:

```
data[ix + iy*dataPointsY]
```

The point of **row**-major is, when the combined index increased by 1, the corresponding **row** index would be same (assuming not overflowing to the next row).

```
double m[4][4];
mp = (double*)m;
mp[1+2*3] == m[2][1]; //true
mp[2+2*3] == m[2][2]; //true
mp[2+2*3] == m[3][1]; //false
```

In general, there's no "right" way to store a matrix. Row major format is also called "C-style" matrix, while column major is called "fortran-style" matrix. The naming is due to different multidimensional array indexing scheme between the two language.